# Metadata Rejected because ads are supposedly not being displayed

Tags: ios, iad

I'm in the middle of getting my very first iOS app pushed out and have been having some trouble with the review process. The app itself is good, but it was recently rejected as **Metadata Rejected** for the following reason:

> Your iTunes Connect settings indicate that your app serves
>   advertisements. However, we were unable to locate ads in your app.

The thing though is that when I run the app on simulators and my test device (an iPhone 4S), the test ads are coming through fine and are consistently located on the bottom of each screen. I've made sure to include the iAd framework in the binary and have signed/agreed to the iAd contract, but when I asked for more information, all I got for a response was

> Your app is metadata rejected as we have asked where to locate ads in
>   your binary, as your app uses IDFA.

Has anyone else encountered something like this before? Is there a final step that I'm missing to have the real ads show up for the Reviewing process? All other topics close to this that I've found seem to refer to options that are no longer on iTunes Connect.

Comment: You say that test ads are showing ok. What about the other set, used in production, if there is any?

Comment: r u using admob or iAd

Comment: for more details go through this https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html

Comment: There's nothing in production yet for me to look at- this is the initial deployment. I'm using only iAd at the moment.

Comment: if you r using iAd i can't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After sending them a screen capture showing the test ads being shown, it's suddenly been approved. How very odd...